# Is there a biblical basis for Zoroastrians worshiping a different God than the God of the Bible?

Tags: biblical-basis, other-religions, 2-chronicles, ezra

If Cyrus king of Persia practiced the Zoroastrian faith and God (presumably Jehovah) moved his heart (2 Chronicles 36:22) and Cyrus prayed to him (Ezra 1:2), what are the biblical bases that Zoroastrians worship a different god than the God of the Bible?

**2 Chronicles 36:22 NIV**

> In the first year of Cyrus king of Persia, in order to fulfill the
>   word of the Lord spoken by Jeremiah, the Lord moved the heart of Cyrus
>   king of Persia to make a proclamation throughout his realm and also to
>   put it in writing:
>
> “This is what Cyrus king of Persia says:
>
> “‘The Lord, the God of heaven, has given me all the kingdoms of the
>   earth and he has appointed me to build a temple for him at Jerusalem
>   in Judah. Any of his people among you may go up, and may the Lord
>   their God be with them.’”

**Ezra 1:2 NIV**

> “This is what Cyrus king of Persia says:
>
> “‘The Lord, the God of heaven, has given me all the kingdoms of the
>   earth and he has appointed me to build a temple for him at Jerusalem
>   in Judah.

I am not looking for opinion, but the biblical bases for either position.

Comment: If you think that Jews, Muslims and Christians worship the same God, I rather think the answer is that they do worship the same God (along with some other groups like the Samaritans).

If you don't think that then you can point to any number of differences in theology - for example they tend to emphasise the power of their satanic figure in a way that might seem uncomfortable to some Christians.

Comment: What is the biblical basis of *'Cyrus king of Persia practiced the Zoroastrian faith'*?

Comment: @FMS Really?  Cyrus was not Jewish and that is not open for debate.

Comment: I believe since you restrict this to biblical basis, the bible must be explicit about the King's faith.

Comment: Psalm 95:5 For all the gods of the Gentiles are devils: but the Lord made the heavens.

Comment: Please explain -1's please.

Comment: For starters, you didn't make your question a question. "Cyrus king of Persia" isn't even a sentence.

Comment: This is a strange question. You've made a conclusion that does not necessarily follow from the evidence given. That when Cyrus prayed that one time it was to Zoroaster (or whoever) instead of to God.

Comment: @fredsbend please remember that only the Hebrews were Jewish and Cyrus was from Persia - a part now known as Iran.  It is commonly accepted that he was Zoroasterian.  Either way it is very clear that he is not Jewish and God was the God of Israel.  For biblical support, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that Cyrus worshiped a different god than the God of the bible is found in

**Isaiah 45:1-4 KJV**

> Thus saith the Lord to his anointed, to Cyrus, whose right hand I have
>   holden, to subdue nations before him; and I will loose the loins of
>   kings, to open before him the two leaved gates; and the gates shall
>   not be shut;
>
> I will go before thee, and make the crooked places straight: I will
>   break in pieces the gates of brass, and cut in sunder the bars of
>   iron:
>
> And I will give thee the treasures of darkness, and hidden riches of
>   secret places, that thou mayest know that I, the Lord, which call thee
>   by thy name, am the God of Israel.
>
> For Jacob my servant's sake, and Israel mine elect, I have even
>   called thee by thy name: I have surnamed thee, **though thou hast not
>   known me.**

While I do not understand how or why God would speak someone who worshiped a different god, apparently he did.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer makes any sense. You may wish to rephrase it.

Comment: I wonder if Cyrus, who did many great things for the Jewish people and is revered in the bible is burning in hell because he didn't know God.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but I'm still having trouble understanding the point of the question.

Comment: And you answer affirms the strangeness of the presumptions in the question. Whether he prayed or not is irrelevant to a God that speaks to whom He will and shows favor on whom He will. The flaw behind the flaw in the premise is that God must wait for us to pray before he interacts with us.

Comment: Originally my question was simply, was Cyrus praying to Jehovah.  Since it is well accepted (except maybe here?) that he was zoroastrian, I wondered how this could be possible.  The questionhasmorphed.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to address all the questions here.

1. **God moved Cyrus heart**. That statement itself doesn't mean that Cyrus became a worshipper of God. God can move the hearts of all sort of people to do all sorts of things (for example read how he moved the heart of Pharoah in Exodus). All it says is God caused Cyrus to do a specific thing, i.e. make a proclamation.
2. **The Lord, the God of heaven, has given me all the kingdoms of the earth** This statement does imply that Cyrus recognizes God in some way. However we don't know if perhaps he recognized God as 'one God among many', and so not a true worshipper. It is also possible that Cyrus couched the proclamation in those terms for his own reasons - perhaps to emphasise to the Israelites his authority.

In any case, none of this implies that Cyrus was a worshipper of God by virtue of his being a Zoroastrian (assuming he was - it's far from certain) and thus doesn't imply that the Zoroastrian God is Yahweh.